# Factoring one variable on the basis of two other variables in R

Tags: r, variables

I'm trying to factor variable "category" by the value of 'high' in variable "value" within "category" with a data set like the following one:

```
sample <- data.frame(
  category = c("cat1", "cat1", "cat1",
               "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", 
               "cat3", "cat3", "cat3"),
  subcat= c("high", "medium", "low", 
           "high", "medium", "low", 
           "high", "medium", "low"),
  value = c(15, 5, 4,
         7, 5, 3,
         19, 4, 3)
)
```

In the end, what I would want is for variable "category" to be factored in this order:

cat3, cat1, cat2.

The factoring needs to be ordered by the value of 'high' (of "subcat" variable) within variable "value".

I'm sure the solution is very simple, but I can't seem to find the correct code for it. Thanks so much in advance!

EDIT: I could of course do this manually, but what I'm looking for is some sort of automated code, as I'm trying to replicate this with a large data set. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming we don't know the correct order of `category` beforehand and we need to find out based on `value`, probably you can use something like this :

```
#Get indices of "high" values
inds <- sample$subcat == 'high'
#Get corresponding category values
category <- sample$category[finds]
#Get corresponding value and order it in descending order to get
#correct order of category value
order_category <- category[order(-sample$value[finds])]
#Order the dataframe based on order_category
sample[order(match(sample$category, order_category)), ]

#  category subcat value
#7     cat3   high    19
#8     cat3 medium     4
#9     cat3    low     3
#1     cat1   high    15
#2     cat1 medium     5
#3     cat1    low     4
#4     cat2   high     7
#5     cat2 medium     5
#6     cat2    low     3
```

Comment: Thanks! :) This was almost perfect. 
The last step I needed, in order to factor variable "category" accordingly, was this:

`sample$category <- factor(sample$category, levels = order_category)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `arrange()` to arrange your dataframe, and `levels()` to re-level.  So, for your dataframe `df`, you can first check the order of the factor levels or, for example the "category" column, with `levels(df$category)`.  You can also use that to reorder the levels.  See the following example, which will probably be all that you need to get you going:

**Dataframe Ordered by Category, then Subcat without re-leveling:**

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(category, subcat)

  category subcat value
1     cat1   high    15
2     cat1    low     4
3     cat1 medium     5
4     cat2   high     7
5     cat2    low     3
6     cat2 medium     5
7     cat3   high    19
8     cat3    low     3
9     cat3 medium     4
```

**Re-Leveling, then Ordering:**

```
levels(df$category) <- c('cat3', 'cat1', 'cat2')
df %>% arrange(category, subcat)

  category subcat value
1     cat3   high    15
2     cat3    low     4
3     cat3 medium     5
4     cat1   high     7
5     cat1    low     3
6     cat1 medium     5
7     cat2   high    19
8     cat2    low     3
9     cat2 medium     4
```

You can alter that to your desire for subcat and value... etc etc.

Comment: What I needed was an automated solution. I was already aware I could define manually the desired order of the values of the variable :)

Comment: What do you mean by "automated"?